# What does WASAPI (Shared) do if the chosen sample rate matches the source?

Tags: windows, audio

I have some audio files, varying from 16/44.1k to 24/192k.

These can, optionally, be re-sampled up to some consistent sample rate like 192k, the max my DAC supports. (Via a software player, such as HQPlayer)

Windows offers the following menu for the WASAPI Shared audio quality:

[image]

Now, here is the question:

What happens when the Source and Windows WASAPI Shared settings match in sample rate? Will Windows just pass it through without re-sampling, which as I understand is not bit-perfect?

My goal is to maximize quality while stuck on WASAPI Shared, because exclusive is a non-option.

I'm currently thinking the best bet is:

- Turn off any re-sampling in software player of choice
- Leave Windows at 24/192k, the best my DAC supports. Not because I want Windows to do the re-sampling as it does a poor job, but just so it won't down-sample high-quality tracks.

Now, if Windows will ignore and pass along audio that already matches the desired sample rate, then I could let something like HQPlayer handle the up-sampling (since it does a great job) and let Windows up-sample other sounds (youtube videos, desktop sounds, etc) since I don't care about their quality.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, AFAIK, you can't really / mathematically resample if the input and output (as per the resampler) sample rate is the same. It's like a [NOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)).

If the output spec you choose in that window / list is the same as the file you play, then there's *a chance* the playback can be *bit-perfect*. (Technically that really depends on whether any manipulation like software volume, or even zero-padding for e.g. 16-bit to 24-bit "conversion", is applied along the pipeline.)

So the best option is to choose the spec with sample rate that matches with most of your audio files (or those that you care about "playback quality" the most), so that resampling is necessary for the least / the playback you care less about quality. (For output bit-depth you should probably pick the highest possible anyway as zero-padding bit-depth "conversion" does not really cause any harm in playback quality, but truncating 24-bit to 16-bit does.)

Note that digital audio doesn't really work in way that "the higher rate the audio is resampled to / the DAC works on, the better the quality". (Although some DAC might perform better on certain or certain family of sample rate; for that you will need to read reviews of your DAC.)

Usually the resampler in those high quality audio player often gives better quality than that in Windows itself, so instead of disabling that, just make them resample to the rate you chose for the device in that window / list.

P.S. [This](https://web.archive.org/web/20200310055211/https://people.xiph.org/%7Exiphmont/demo/neil-young.html) might interest you by the way. I am not in position to say how true/scientific it is though.

Comment: Regarding the article - I am aware of it, however, this may be a separate issue as this is what goes into the DAC and not the source itself. 

All DACs have to do upsampling. However, they often perform the calculation in a limited way with 100's to 1000's of TAPs. The idea is that we can perform that operation ourselves in software or dedicated hardware better than the DAC can, so it can better re-create the audio.

Comment: `All DACs have to do upsampling.` Although I don't know the exact difference, the process that occurred in the DAC (of "the DAC" / the "sound card") is called oversampling, which is quite a different thing from upsampling/resampling and has nothing to do with what sample rate it supports. What you are talking about is "hardware" resampling done by some DSP/controller chip of the "sound card", which is rarely found in those "DAC for audiophile" as they do not accept multiple input signal and/or do hardware mixing like some old-fashion SoundBlaster.

Comment: Also I think the article implies that downsampling to 48KHz and let the DAC work at that rate could possibly do more good than harm. At least that's the reason I linked it, as an *alternate* consideration to the suggestion in my answer. (It's even more practical if your archive/library is mainly 48KHz -- simply downsample for those pointlessly high rate audio instead of pointlessly and unnecssarily upsample for those with a sensical rate.)

Answer (score 0):

> Will Windows just pass it through without re-sampling, which as I understand is not bit-perfect?

This is a somewhat non-sensical statement. If you "pass it through without re-sampling" it *will* be "bit-perfect", *but* it will sound distorted in terms of pitch and playback speed.

So resampling is necessary when playback occurs at a different rate than that of the input/source.

Your real question probably is whether you want your "DAC" or Windows to do this resampling. Which one is better is hard to say without knowing what algorithms they each implement. (Typically, you'd want at least cubic resampling, but sometimes supersampling aka oversampling is done first, in high-quality implementations.)

On this issue of Windows' resample "being bad", people sometimes [confuse](https://www.audiosciencereview.com/forum/index.php?threads/windows-resampling-not-actually-that-bad.9092/) bugs in the audio drivers for whatever hardware they are using for bugs in Windows.